# SAP (RFC 2974) and SDP (RFC 2327) Head size

Tags: c++, rfc, sdp

I'm learning c(++) and trying to implement SAP and SDP announcement protocols.
Currently, I'm following the RFCs and some code from Git Hub (like gestream and mumudvb). There I can see that after the SAP header, there are 8 bytes "head" before the SDP text.
I could find such instructions in the RFCs or at least I didn't understand such a thing. This is my first try to implement something from RFC and I'm a bit confused about this "head".

Sorry, if my question looks dumb, but I want to understand it.

Thanks

I've checked the implemented SAP services and the RFC but I could not find why there are 8 bytes there.

Comment: `There I can see` Where exactly? `Git Hub (like gestream and mumudvb` Where exactly - please post links. I can't find "gestream". Ach - RFC is in the title, sorry.

Comment: @KamilCuk mumudvb implementation of SAP serverice can be seen [here](https://github.com/braice/MuMuDVB/blob/mumudvb2/src/sap.c) and the [RFC 2974](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2974) and [RFC 2327](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2327).

I had a typo in the title but I fix it.

Comment: Thx. `can be seen here` - and where there do you see the 8 bytes? `There I can see that after the SAP header, there are 8 bytes "head"` Where is "there"? In github - if so which line which project? Why I am asking - please kindly post what you "see", the source, with your interpretation of what you see.

Comment: @KamilCuk look [here](https://github.com/braice/MuMuDVB/blob/5e9959e366b815ac498f2dc2823ac028d59a5d5f/src/sap.c#L332)

Comment: The `SAP_HEAD_LEN4` macro is of interest here?

Comment: sorry, this is first time asking a question for many years, and I'm still confused

Comment: yes this is the thing that I want to understand, why it is added

Comment: I do not know, it is there in section 5 in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2974 . Please edit your question to add the relevant information and links to projects and line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

We need https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2974 section 5 page 6:

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   | V=1 |A|R|T|E|C|   auth len    |         msg id hash           |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                                                               |
   :                originating source (32 or 128 bits)            :
   :                                                               :
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    optional authentication data               |
   :                              ....                             :
   *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
   |                      optional payload type                    |
   +                                         +-+- - - - - - - - - -+
   |                                         |0|                   |
   + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-+                   |
   |                                                               |
   :                            payload                            :
   |                                                               |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

We also need parts from mumudvb2 sap.h

```
#define SAP_HEADER4_BYTE0 0x20 /**00100000 : version 1 and nothing else*/
#define SAP_HEADER4_BYTE1 0x00 /**No auth header*/

#define SAP_HEADER6_BYTE0 0x30 /**00110000 : version 1 and IPv6*/
#define SAP_HEADER6_BYTE1 0x00 /**No auth header*/

#define SAP_HEAD_LEN4 8
#define SAP_HEAD_LEN6 20
```

and parts of sap.c https://github.com/braice/MuMuDVB/blob/mumudvb2/src/sap.c#L267 related to ipv4 handling:

```
    sap_message4->buf[0]=SAP_HEADER4_BYTE0;
    sap_message4->buf[1]=SAP_HEADER4_BYTE1;
    //Hash of SAP message: see end of this function
    sap_message4->buf[2]=0;
    sap_message4->buf[3]=0;

[...]

        log_message( log_module, MSG_DEBUG,"sap sending ipv4  address : %s (binary : 0x%x)\n",sap_p->sap_sending_ip4, ip4);
        memcpy (sap_message4->buf + 4, &ip4, 4);

[...]

sprintf(temp_string,"application/sdp");
if(channel->socketOut4)
{
    memcpy(sap_message4->buf + SAP_HEAD_LEN4, temp_string, strlen(temp_string));
    sap_message4->len=SAP_HEAD_LEN4+strlen(temp_string);
    sap_message4->buf[sap_message4->len]=0;
    sap_message4->len++;
```

The first 4 bytes are `| V=1 |A|R|T|E|C|   auth len    |         msg id hash          |` and the next 4 bytes is `originating source (32 [...] bits`.

That said, I do fully understand your confusion. It is part of the protocol, the `payload type` set to application/sdp mime type goes after what is in front of it.

Comment: after some dig into C pointers and your answer, I figured it out that my confusion comes from the pointer itself.

Comment: memcopy takes a pointer as first argument and in order to add the temp_string, I have to move the pointer to the correct address (by adding 8 bytes to the char) in order to copy the content of temp_string. Still learning C